# Perform static analysis over executable Jar

Tags: static-analysis

Can you perform static analysis over executable Jar files ?
What I did so far is decompile (JD GUI) the jar to get source code excerpts. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Check out Find Security Bugs

Comment: @paj28 What do you mean ? Is it a website or a tool ?

Comment: @paj28 OK. You meant this https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/    ?   I'm talking about executable jar files.... not an actual project with all the source code and all....

Comment: Yeah. I think it can work on a jar. If not - decompile first then FSB

Answer (score 1):

> Can you perform static analysis over executable Jar files?

Yes. Static analysis just means that you are not actually executing the software during your analysis.

> What I did so far is decompile (JD GUI) the jar to get source code excerpts. Is there a better way to do this ?

Decompiling the jar file is a great way to start, and JD GUI is a handy tool to help you decompile. Now you just have to dive in and actually figure out what the Java code is doing. Good luck!